# JPF on a website, how to get it working right?

Tags: php, html, jpeg

I am trying to optimize my website using pagespeed, and I got the advice to use JPEG2000 instead of normal JPG. So I converted all my images but when I changed the images it doesn't show on my laptop. So I checked "caniuse" and now I see that this extension is only supported on mobile phones (android and ios)

So how do I implement this in my website? Do I need to use javascript to change the extension to jpf if the device is a mobile phone?

I use picture and srcset based on screensize, but that doesn't work if I drag my screen smaller on my laptop.. Does anyone know how to use this new JPEG2000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone gave you some really bad advice. Support for JPEG 2000 is very limited. It's likely you system simply cannot decode the image.

The problem with the JPEG standards is they are done from an academic egghead perspective. The original JPEG standard was entirely unimplementable. At the time there was no good 24-bpp format for photographs available so, as fate would have it a group of developers stepped in and filled the gaps in the standard. That resulted in the JFIF file format and the IJG encoder/decoder.

The JPEG2000 standard is even worse from an implementation point of view. It contains no end-to-end description of the encoding and decoding process. Add to that JPEG2000 provides limited benefits over existing image formats so there is is little incentive for developers to wade through the confusing standard and create implementations for it. Compare the PNG standard to the JPEG2000 and you will quickly see the difference. The PNG standard is a guide for implementors while the JPEG2000 standard seems like an academic paper.

As such, there is little incentive to adopt JPEG2000. It's just one of a myriad of image format out there that are rarely used.

Comment: Ok that's weird that Pagespeed is recomending that format. What do you recommend for mobile devices? Just use JPG or PNG?

Comment: JPEG for photographs. PNG for drawings.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know why Pagespeed recommend this? (Also other file formates but they claim JPEG is not good enough)

Comment: i'm no familiar with pagespeed.

Comment: aha ok, that's the google tool to check the website for optimization

Comment: i just converted my site's images to jpf as par Google search console's suggestion to improve seo. now all those images are blank even on Chrome Google owns browser. Tha's pretty rubbish of Google for doing the recommendation and not even supported by it's own browser.

Comment: use WebP images for modern webpages, maybe with combination of SVG for icons etc. All modern browsers already support those.  However, you can still stick to jpg and png if they are well optimized

Answer (score 3):

JPEG 2000 is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=JPEG2000) by Safari and no other browser.

Using it as the default image format is a terrible idea.

You could use [srcset](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2015/01/14/using-webp-jpeg2000-jpegxr-apng-now-with-picturefill-and-modernizr/#using-picturefill) to provide images in a range of formats for clients with different levels of support.